# Child View Controller Resizing

Tags: ios

I have two child view controllers that are nib files that I display on a parent view controller in the storyboard using:

```
[self addChildViewController:vc1];
[vc2 willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

[self transitionFromViewController:vc2
    toViewController:vc1
    duration:1.0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
    animations:^{}
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [vc2 removeFromParentViewController];
        [vc1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }];
```

I set the child controllers view's size as free form. I want them to size correctly when using both iPhone4 and iPhone5. By correctly I mean I want the child controller's view and subviews to shrink on iPhone4 to fit the whole view onto the screen and expand to fit the screen on iPhone5. Right now I have the child controller views set for iPhone5. I usually just use IB's autoresizing to make the subviews size correctly on both phones, but it is not working for child view controllers.

I also tried setting it programmatically in the parent controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.vc1.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

When that did work I tried setting it in the child controller's `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Which also didn't work. So, how do I make child view controller's resize correctly in both iPhone4 and iPhone5?

Comment: Please post the code where you add and size the viewController views. Also, are you sure **auto layout** is turned off?

Comment: My first section of code is where I add it. (vc1 and vc2) The second is where I am trying to autosize it. What else did you want exactly? Yes, auto layout is turned off.

Comment: Old question, but I think it is because you have flexible bottom and top margins. You want the the child to snap to the parent's edges then to match the parent's height and width as the parent resizes.
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

Comment: Sadly I do not have access to this code/a Mac anymore, but thanks for the comment :)